# How to insert multiple table rows with mutiple values? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with multiple input rows like this one:

```
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class = "shelf" name="shelf[]" type="text" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="book" name="book[][]" multiple="multiple" required>
                    <option>...</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

User inputs names of the shelves and selects multiple books for each shelf. Shelves are inserted in one table and their IDs and selected book IDs are inserted into another table. Basically, like this:

```
foreach ($request->shelf as $item =>$v){
    $id = Shelf::insertGetId(
        ['name' => $request->shelf[$item]]
    );

    foreach ($request->shelf[$item] as $it =>$v) {
        $data2 = array(
            'fk_Shelf' => $id,
            'fk_Book' => $request->book[$item][$it],
        );
        Shelf_Book::insert($data2);
    }
}
```

My second foreach doesn't work though because it always inserts only one of the selected books. How should I solve this?

Comment: you need two foreach and not  foreach inside a foreach

Answer (score 0):

Seems like on the second for loop you are trying to iterate again over shelf, but it only has one dimension, maybe you meant to iterate over book[$item]?

```php
foreach ($request->shelf as $shelf_key => $shelf_value){
    $id = Shelf::insertGetId(
        ['name' => $shelf_value]
    );

    foreach ($request->book[$shelf_key] as $book_key => $book_value) {
        $data2 = array(
            'fk_Shelf' => $id,
            'fk_Book' => $book_value,
        );
        Shelf_Book::insert($data2);
    }
}
```